# React app not working in IE11 (have tried polyfills)

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

Our react app, built with create react app, isn't working in IE11 (development and production). Up till now we have used core.js to polyfill our code, but suddenly IE11 has stopped working. Initially we are met with one of the two following errors:

1. SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'
2. SCRIPT5009: 'Proxy' is undefined

It appears that the App component isn't loading at all in IE11.

We have tried the following without luck:

- Object.entries polyfill (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- react-app-polyfill (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md)
- removing react-pose completely
- switching between node versions
- we also tried upgrading all packages

Our index.js file has this at the top:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
import 'proxy-polyfill';
```

After we have implemented the above solutions we are left with a styled-components error:
SCRIPT5022: : Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined.

Our packages.json contains the following:

```
      "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "axios-token-interceptor": "^0.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "formik": "^1.5.1",
    "framer-motion": "^2.6.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "polished": "^3.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-countup": "^4.1.3",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.6.2",
    "react-div-100vh": "^0.3.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-player": "^1.11.0",
    "react-pose": "^4.0.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.10",
    "react-spinners": "^0.5.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.0",
    "styled-icons": "^9.3.0",
    "styled-normalize": "^8.0.6",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/react": "^5.0.11",
    "babel-plugin-react-remove-properties": "^0.3.0",
    "cypress-testing-library": "^3.0.1",
    "env-cmd": "^8.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.8.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.0.2",
    "jest-styled-components": "^6.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "react-testing-library": "^7.0.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome versions",
      "last 2 firefox versions",
      "last 2 edge versions",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "production": [
      ">1%",
      "last 4 versions",
      "Firefox ESR",
      "not ie < 11"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to locate the problematic code for the latest error? It can be related to some  syntax related issue. I suggest you refer to [this](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1449#issuecomment-420087359) answer may give you some hint.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across the solution to one of your problem. It turns out that the `framer-motion` library is not compatible with IE, because since v2 the library uses "proxy", which is not compatible with polyfills that react app uses for IE. You can see this [here](https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/664#issuecomment-664351543).

This solves your problem for 'Proxy' is undefined

Comment: Many thanks for this. I actually missed this at the time, but from memory what you said is exactly the solution we found.